# Assigning .rda to an object and using predict in that object in R

Tags: r, object, load, predict

I created a model using some data. Say my model is

```
x_glm<-glm(X~Y+Z)
```

Now I saved the x_glm

```
   save(x_glm, "/home/Dav/x_glm.rda")
```

Now I want to load that model to an object and use it for another prediction

```
mymodel<- load("/home/Dav/x_glm.rda)

predict(mymodel, newdata = data2, type = "response")
```

does not work!

But if I load it and not pass it to an object then

`predict(x_glm, newdata = data2, type ="response")` works.

How can I pass the model to an object and call prediction on that object?

Answer (score 0):

`load` and `save` are made for saving multiple objects in one file. `load` loads **all objects** from a saved environment, and the result cannot be assigned. Instead, you end up loading the same names that were saved.

For a single object `saveRDS` and `readRDS` are more appropriate. They do not preserve the original names of the object saved, and the output from `readRDS` can and should be assigned. Good practice is to use the `.rds` file extension here.

```
saveRDS(x_glm, "x_glm.rds")
mymodel = readRDS("x_glm.rds")
```

If you need to be safer with `load` and an environment saved in a `rda` file, you can create a new environment, load into that environment, and then pull objects out one at a time into your current environment, something like this:

```
my_env = new.env()
load("x_glm.rda", envir = my_env)
ls(envir = my_env) # find the name of the object you want
my_object = my_env$name_of_loaded_object
```

A risk of `load`ing in to your current environment is that any objects you have with the same names as objects being `load`ed will be overwritten.